# Is there a way to create dynamic references for HTML to be used by Angular?

Tags: angular

Sometimes we may create some useful references for elements on HTML and use it in our angular code, like:

```html
<input #myInput>
```

I would like to now if there is a way to dynamically create these references, something like:

```html
<div *ngFor="items of list; let i = index">
  <input #myInput-{{i}}/>
</div>
```

It would generate #myInput-0, #myInput-1... #myInput-N.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@ViewChildren** to achieve it.

TS:

`import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';`

```
  @ViewChildren('myInput') myInputs: QueryList<ElementRef>


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myInputs._results);
  }
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of list">
  <input #myInput/>
</div>
```

**See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fraqe1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**